# Colon in constructor (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ionic2

What ':' stands for in this code?

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(nav: NavController) {
    this.nav = nav;
  }
}
```

Code taken from: 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/

Comment: That's a type annotation. It's not standard JS.

Comment: Thank you, is there a resource on the web on this topic?

Comment: Depends on the system that is used. Since this appears to be Angular, this could very well be TypeScript. I didn't see it mentioned in the docs though.

Answer (score 1):

The type annotation is used by Type Script:

> A typed superset of Javascript

For more information follow the [quickstart Guide on Type Script](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html)

Comment: Ok it seems Type Script